# Tool to automate Docker Swarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have followed the Docker Docs about setting up Swarm on Virtualbox.
I suppose it is the same procedure to set it up on AWS, Azure or DigitalOcean.
It is a lot to do manually every time .

Is there a tool to automate this?

I would like to use something to set up and scale Swarm like Compose does for Docker .

Maybe I would start with one AWS instance and 2-3 containers and then scale them up to 100 containers and the instances to scale accordingly. Then I would want to scale down to 2 instances and the rest would shut down.

Does something like this exist ?

Comment: The docker solution to this is [infrakit](https://github.com/docker/infrakit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) for configuring the Swarm master, Swarm nodes, and all the required cluster discovery. Ansible is a general IT automation tool, but it comes with a very powerful [Docker module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_module.html) that allows to set up Docker Swarm easily.

[This GitHub repository](https://github.com/technolo-g/docker-swarm-demo) shows a good example how to set up Swarm with Ansible.

Comment: Thanks, I have used Ansible before but didn't think of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid manual configurations but still get the required high availability and cost efficiency, try to run Docker Swarm template pre-packaged by Jelastic:

- it has built-in automatic clustering and scaling
- the installation is performed automatically and you'll get full access to the cluster via intuitive UI
- containers are running directly on bare metal, so no need to reserve full VMs for each service (and you can choose the datacenter you want to run your project on)
- the payment is done based on actual consumption of RAM and CPU
- containers are automatically distributed across different hardware servers that increases high availability

The details about the package and [installation steps are in this article](https://jelastic.com/blog/docker-swarm-auto-clustering-and-scaling-with-paas/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) for provisioning hosts and configuring swarm easily ([example](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-w-machine/)).

The Docker Ecosystem includes also managed solutions like [Tutum](https://www.tutum.co/) or [Docker Cloud](https://cloud.docker.com/) to achieve easily what you want.

Comment: Thanks molivier for the response. I have completed this tutorial and it is really time consuming to do that every time. Tutum has been 'bought' by Docker forming the Docker Cloud you refer to. I have in my todo list to check if Cloud and AWS ECS fit my case.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [devopsbyte.com](https://devopsbyte.com/create-a-docker-swarm-cluster-using-ansible/) blog, which covers how to set up a docker swarm cluster using ansible